# How to get specific values from a xml file into csv file using python?

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I am trying to extract object, xmin, ymin, xmax and xmax value of every object tag there is.

```
XML

<annotation>
    <folder>Plates_Number</folder>
    <filename>1.png</filename>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>294</width>
        <height>60</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>2</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>1</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>40</xmin>
            <ymin>1</ymin>
            <xmax>69</xmax>
            <ymax>42</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>10</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>67</xmin>
            <ymin>3</ymin>
            <xmax>101</xmax>
            <ymax>43</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>1</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>122</xmin>
            <ymin>2</ymin>
            <xmax>153</xmax>
            <ymax>45</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>10</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>151</xmin>
            <ymin>3</ymin>
            <xmax>183</xmax>
            <ymax>44</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>2</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>186</xmin>
            <ymin>4</ymin>
            <xmax>216</xmax>
            <ymax>47</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>5</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>214</xmin>
            <ymin>5</ymin>
            <xmax>245</xmax>
            <ymax>46</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

This is what I tried but didn't get the expected result

```
python

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

tree = ET.parse("1.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

# open a file for writing

data = open('test.csv', 'r+')

# create the csv writer object

csvwriter = csv.writer(data)
data_head = []

count = 0
for member in root.findall('object'):
    obj = []
    bndbox_list = []
    if count == 0:
        name = member.find('name').tag
        data_head.append(name)
        bndbox = member[4].tag
        data_head.append(bndbox)
        csvwriter.writerow(data_head)
        count = count + 1

    name = member.find('name').text
    obj.append(name)
    bndbox = member[4][0].text
    bndbox_list.append(bndbox)
    xmin = member[4][1].text
    bndbox_list.append(xmin)
    ymin = member[4][2].text
    bndbox_list.append(ymin)
    xmax = member[4][3].text
    bndbox_list.append(xmax)
    ymax = member[4][4].text
    bndbox_list.append(ymax)
    obj.append(bndbox)
    csvwriter.writerow(data)
data.close()
```

I expect 
Name xmin ymin xmax ymax
2    40   1     69   42
10   67   3     101  43
1    122  2     153  45
10   151  3     183  44
2    186  4     216  47
5    214  5     245  46

but I am only getting these two header

Name bndbox

and no value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), you could use

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(input_xml_string)
tgs = soup.find_all('object', 'xml')
l = [(i.find('name').string, i.xmin.string, i.ymin.string, i.xmax.string, i.ymax.string) for i in tgs]
```

where `input_xml_string` is the input xml in string form.

`soup` would be a [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#beautifulsoup) object which is a representation of the xml tree.

An xml [parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) is used.

Then the `find_all()` function is used to find all the `<object>` tags in the xml. The result is stored in `tgs`.

Now from the elements in `tgs`, which would be children tags of `<object>`, we select the tags we need, which are [`Tag`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag) objects, and get their values using their `string` attribute.

We could have accessed the value in `name` using its `string` attribute but `name` is the name of an attribute of the 
`Tag` class. So we first used `find()` to get the `<name>` child of `<object>` and then we got its content.

Now if we print the values in `l`,

```
for i in l:
    print(i)
```

we would get,

```
('2', '40', '1', '69', '42')
('10', '67', '3', '101', '43')
('1', '122', '2', '153', '45')
('10', '151', '3', '183', '44')
('2', '186', '4', '216', '47')
('5', '214', '5', '245', '46')
```

Answer (score 1):

code :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse('file.xml').getroot()


for type_tag in root.findall('object'):
    name = type_tag.find('name').text
    xmin = type_tag.find('bndbox/xmin').text
    ymin = type_tag.find('bndbox/ymin').text
    xmax = type_tag.find('bndbox/xmax').text
    ymax = type_tag.find('bndbox/ymax').text

    print([name,xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax])
```

output:

```
['2', '40', '1', '69', '42']
['10', '67', '3', '101', '43']
['1', '122', '2', '153', '45']
['10', '151', '3', '183', '44']
['2', '186', '4', '216', '47']
['5', '214', '5', '245', '46']
```