# How should I extract the contents within XML using python into CSV

Tags: python, xml, csv, tags

This is my xml

```
</testsuites>`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<testsuites>
<testsuite name="Test" tests="7" failure="1" timestamp="2019-12-11T11:33:16.057Z">
  <testcase **name**="02. Create pinboard" classname="Testcase" **time**="88.832">
  </testcase>
 <testcase **name**="17. Adding Data labels to a Geo chart" classname="Testcases" **time**="68.39">
    <**failure message**="Step Failed: Element not found More info at: https://"www.google.com"/>
  </testcase>
</testsuite>
</testsuites>`
```

From this I want to extract values of name ,time ,failure message using python into csv.
How I should do this.Please suggest

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56020248/how-to-get-specific-values-from-a-xml-file-into-csv-file-using-python)

Comment: What is the problem? Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood, you want to extract informations from .XML file and write it (maybe after some post-processing) in .CSV file.

To do so, my advice would be to organize your code with:

- a reader part: take the .xml file as input and store information in your `data structure`. You can easily parse xml files using [xml library](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/xml.html).
- a writer part: take the `data structure` as input (generally iterate over it) to write in the .csv output file. You can do it with [csv library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) or simply with classical open file method (since csv is easy to format).

Depends on your code, each part could be a function (but also a class or a package).
The `data structure` is to build for your needs but you can store every data in lists, dictionaries, arrays or DataFrame.. Note that with library like `numpy` / `pandas` there is already function to write contents of an array / DataFrame in .csv file.

Since it was not clear, I supposed from your post that you didn't know how to start. Hope this can help you to attack your problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,utils
html = '''
</testsuites>`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<testsuites>
<testsuite name="Test" tests="7" failure="1" timestamp="2019-12-11T11:33:16.057Z">
  <testcase **name**="02. Create pinboard" classname="Testcase" **time**="88.832">
  </testcase>
 <testcase **name**="17. Adding Data labels to a Geo chart" classname="Testcases" **time**="68.39">
    <**failure message**="Step Failed: Element not found More info at: https://www.google.com"/>
  </testcase>
</testsuite>
</testsuites>`
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
row = []
row.append(["name","tests", "failure","timestamp","testcase_name","testcase_classname","testcase_time","failure_message"])
testsuites = doc.selects('testsuites>testsuite')
for t in testsuites:
  for testcase in t.testcases:
    message = testcase.select('**failure>message**()')
    row.append([t.name,t.tests, t.failure,t.timestamp,testcase['**name**'],testcase['classname'],testcase['**time**'],message])

utils.save2csv("test.csv",row)
```

Result:

```
name,tests,failure,timestamp,testcase_name,testcase_classname,testcase_time,failure_message
Test,7,1,2019-12-11T11:33:16.057Z,02. Create pinboard,Testcase,88.832,
Test,7,1,2019-12-11T11:33:16.057Z,17. Adding Data labels to a Geo chart,Testcases,68.39,Step Failed: Element not found More info at: https://www.google.com
```